# Maven default evaluation of the pom xml file

Tags: maven

We do not have project design in parent and module way.We have project A and project B . Project A has dependency of project B . we passing the version of the dependency jar by command prompt in eclipse, Its compiling and install properly. but its pom shows always error.and  error is like

> Missing artifact
>   com.testdependency:testdependency:jar:org.apache.maven.model.Build@5ae16e48

Passed the build parameter by command line like -Dbuild. Is there any way resolve this ?

Comment: I added the default value for the parameter then it does not show the error .

is it correct way?

Answer (score 0):

`pom.xml` would need the dependencies present in your local `.m2` repository. If you don't install the dependencies to your local repository, `pom.xml` can't find them. So, run a build on your dependency project with goals selected as `clean install`, which should insall the artifact to your local repository. Then in your eclipse, right click on the main project and execute `Maven -> Update Project`. This should resolve your issue.

Refer to this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository) for the details on the repositories

Comment: I added the default value for the parameter then it does not show the error .

is it correct way?

Comment: what default value? can you give some code snippet?

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>com.TestMV1</groupId>
      <artifactId>TestMV1</artifactId>
      <version>${version}</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: In my project TESTMV this TestMV1 is refered as dependency.

we are actually want to  share the version of both the project .
runconfiguration we want to run the both project by one configuration in commad -Dversion

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You said you added the default value. What was the default value? If you are running build for `TestMV1` with version `0.0.1` in `pom.xml`, then you should add the dependency in `pom.xml` of `TESTMV` as `<dependency> <groupId>com.TestMV1</groupId> <artifactId>TestMV1</artifactId> <version>0.0.1</version> </dependency>`. Unless you have built `TestMV1`, you can't refer it in `TESTMV`